# How can I Eslint only changed lines of code

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, eslint

I need a way to run ESLint on only the code lines or blocks that have changed on a branch.  The idea is, that we have a big old code base and we want to enforce ESLint rules *at least* moving forward.

I implemented it in CI linting all the files that changed in a PR. But people are touching one line in a file and all of a sudden they have to fix 77 ESLint errors.

Personally I'm not at all concerned for them, but they are bigger and stronger than me and I need to make some baby steps here I guess.

So I can get a list of all the files changed for a particular branch. And I suspect I can do a diff and parse it and pull out all the line numbers that changed and then run ESLint and filter the results by the line numbers but this sounds like a colossal pain.

My question is is there not some better real way to do this?  I'm not the first person to need this.

Just to be clear I understand that this "requirement" is strictly for edge cases such as mine where the burden of a whole file change is just too great.  It's not optimal. It is sub-optimal, but if I don't do this I don't get anything so I have to pick my battles.

Comment: But if you *just* look at the diffs you'd still miss problems. Let's say you have `let x = 42;` and then `foo(x)`. One commit deletes the function call. Now you have an unused variable `x` but scanning the changed lines doesn't reveal that. You can also have the opposite issue, a commit adds `bar(y)`. But `y` is never defined. There is no possible way to find this problem from scanning just the changes.

Comment: I like it, the more arguments against the better.  My plan is to just use the line level things like react/no-spread-props which can cause you to have to change many files as you go deeper and deeper ( more evidence that's it's an important rule ).  This way people will stop doing it but they wont be completely screwed if they change a file with one.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote an ESLint plugin for this exact use-case. We had an existing config and wanted to do a major overhaul of the config, but didn’t want to have to fix all errors (which were previously defined as not being errors) in one go, because it would’ve been a terrible RIO.

This plugin instead allows you to only diff whatever you’ve staged and we run it in a pre-commit. Our regular “lint”-script in package.json doesn’t use the plugin, so it still shows all errors/warnings there.

Here’s a link to it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-diff

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much Patrick. I wish there was something like this for prettier --write as well.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I installed your plugin but I notice that it doesn't seem to run against my diff in VSCode. I have this in my .eslintrc:
```
  "extends": [
    "plugin:diff/diff",
    "eslint:recommended"
  ],
```
and when I remove the "plugin:diff/diff", my ESLint runs against everything including my diff, but when I add in "plugin:diff/diff", it does not run against anything. Do you know why that it might be?

Comment: Hi @VMS , I am also facing same problem, were you able to resolve it ? could you please help me here.

@V

Comment: Hey @MadhuAvinash, unfortunately I was not able to resolve it. I think I ended up trying a few other plugins but did not pursue it much further, since linting was not a critical need for us.

Comment: for me it doesn't work as well :( it's not linting any files

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use some tool like [Review Dog](https://github.com/reviewdog/reviewdog). It will add review feedbacks on your PR/MR based on the linter result that are part of the diff only:

> reviewdog provides a way to post review comments to code hosting service, such as GitHub, automatically by integrating with any linter tools with ease. It uses an output of lint tools and posts them as a comment if findings are in diff of patches to review.

Btw, this [article](https://dev.to/dcwither/adding-new-lint-rules-without-the-fuss-34a2) helped me figure this out and propose alternative solutions for your use case if you're interested.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The exact answer for this question is this:

**AIM** : To lint only the changed lines before committing rather linting the staged files.

To achieve this we should use **Husky**(a pre-commit hook),**lint-staged** and a special dependency called **eslint-plugin-diff**;

The flow here is : when you are about to make a commit husky will be triggered which will trigger lint-staged which is responsible for extracting all the staged files and run eslint on the files.

We have to configure the eslint to make this work to lint only the changed lines in a commit.

These are the steps to do this:

i)Configure husky and lint-staged as in the normal way

ii) You will have .eslintrc file,You have to create another file ".eslint.husky.js"(in root)

iii) Copy all the codes from `.eslintrc` to `.eslint.husky.js` file

iv) In the `.eslint.husky.js` file, in the extends section add **"plugin:diff/diff"**(must add dependency : `eslint-plugin-diff`)
refer:https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-diff

v)This is the main step you are going to do, After configuring lint-staged you will have `.lintstagedrc` file. In that file you have to config the file that should use the configuration in `.eslint.husky.js` for linting
The file should look like

```
{
  "**/*.{js,jsx,scss,}": ["eslint --config .eslintrc.husky.js"]
}
```

All set now you can commit and check for the results.
You can ask "Why should I create a new file and add "plugin:diff/diff" to the extends section , I can directly do the thing in `.eslintrc` file ".

Yes you can do so but all the linters are disabled and no errors will appear on the editor, But it will show the errors during commit... Thats all ,Hope it Helped

Comment: This is exactly what I also did and seems to be reasonable way to have VSCode show errors and also have linters help before pre-commit hook. Hope, fix comes soon to the eslint-plugin-diff.

Answer (score 0):

2024: modern, maintained, linter-agnostic solution to this problem might be https://github.com/hallettj/git-format-staged

Source: https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit

Still, thanks for all the hard eslint-plugin-diff work @patrick-eriksson.