# How can I run Eslint only on changed lines of code

Tags: reactjs, gitlab, eslint

I want to run eslint on my react project in gitlab pipelines. This linting should run only on the changed lines of code but not on the whole file.

I am aware that we can run on the whole file but this could be a costly work when its a legacy code.

I tried eslint-diff its giving error as **/usr/bin/env: node --harmony** in gitlab but works fine in local

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074535/how-can-i-eslint-only-changed-lines-of-code

Comment: I am seeing eslint-plugin-diff is not working as expected. It is scanning all the files not just the changed.

Comment: I will like to also find an answer for this problem. - @ShrikanthHathwar

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62074535/how-can-i-eslint-only-changed-lines-of-code